# mono 2.6 and visual studio 10

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, mono

When I tried to run a binary (exe file) that was made with Visual Studio 10 from mono 2.6/Mac, I get the following warning.

```
WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
Using default runtime: v1.1.4322
```

How can I disable this message with mono? Is there a way from Visual Studio not to show this message with mono/Mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mono 2.6.x does not support the .NET 4.0 runtime version, so it's falling back to the default version, .NET 1.1.

I suggest you install [Mono 2.8](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.8) which was released yesterday and which supports 4.0.

Alternatively, you can change your VS project to target .NET 2.0/3.0/3.5.